# Ошибка: incompatible magic value 1013478509 in class file com/abs/ui/Signer Applet.

Tags: java

Как настроить JAVA, чтобы устранить проблему:

```
incompatible magic value 1013478509 in class file com/abs/ui/Signer Applet.
```

Comment: @Diiimaaa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Переводим `1013478509` в hex, -> `0x3C68746D`. А теперь, разобрав по байтах, в символы. Например, [этим сервисом](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm). Получается `<htm`. Ничего не напоминает? Это начало html файла!

Почему так получается? При загрузке java файла виртуальная машина проверяет его на корректность. Самая первая проверка - это прочитать первые 4 байта и сверить. Они всегда одинаковые для скомпилированных java файлов и равны `0xCAFEBABE` (hex: `3405691582`).

Вывод. Скорее всего, вместо обычного class файла Вы пытаетесь запустить html страницу. Виртуальная java машина этого не умеет. Этот файл мог попасть, если веб-сервер не нашел указанный файл на сервере и отдал 404 страницу.